# Using XML-RPC in iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-rpc

Is it possible to use XML-RPC calls in iPhone application (what approaches are the best)?
Are there any constraints with XML-RPC?

Thank you,
Paul

Answer (score 3):

I have recently come across this library, take a look at the description at the end.

Hope you find it useful.

https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the WordPress for iOS app. It's completely open source and uses an XML-RPC library.

http://ios.wordpress.org/

Comment: To be precise, it uses Jonathan Wight's TouchXML library (https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML). Thanks for the tip.