# Remote procedural calls over socket.io in native iOS applications?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, rpc, socket.io

Is it possible to do remote procedural calls over socket.io in native iOS applications?

Would it be easier to do in a Titanium built application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's not udp you could probably write a client for it.  However, curious on google I found: http://www.ziconic.com/2010/11/simple-ajax-style-rpc-code-in-your-ios.html which will be more of what you want I think. This [Using XML-RPC in iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975796/using-xml-rpc-in-iphone-apps) says that it handles xml on the iphone and there's https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml which should help with that.

Hope it helps a bit. RPC documentation in xml is readily available.

Answer (score 4):

This Objective-C Socket.IO client library is what you're looking for:

https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc

Comment: Probably a better answer than mine, I don't do IOS. I was just interested in the RPC side of it.